# Trigger a downtime with an Event

Tags: anylogic

In my model I have a source, quee, service and sink. The service represents an equipment.I am trying to add a downtime to the service that only occurs in a specific occasion. This downtime represents a change of tool of the equipment, so when goes from manufacturing a product A to a product B we need to apply a downtime of 10 min to simulate the tool change.

I used the following line in the on enter box of the service:
[image: Properties screenshot of service]

But an error pops up: NullPointerException.

Do you know how to solve this or maybe another and better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Use the Downtime block, that is what it is there for :) See the help: https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/downtime.html